# R: Not able to update a grid (grid package) in a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, r-grid

I am using functions (like pushViewport(), grobs, etc.) from the grid package to plot a drawing in a shiny app. I plot it using renderPlot(). In the server script it looks a bit like this:

```
  output$myPlot <- renderPlot({
    load("list_with_grid_paramaters.RData")        
    source("script_that_builds_the_grid.R")        
  },width = 800, height = 800)
```

When I start the application it builds the grid properly. In my app I can change the parameters of the grid and save it as a new `list_with_grid_paramaters.RData`. When I try to renderPlot() the grid again (using an actionbutton) after changing the paramaters, the plot doesn't update.

Does anyone have an idea about what could be the case here? Most appreciated!

Comment: I'm quite sure that I'd be able to answer your question if I had a reproducible example in hand ;)

Comment: I understand, I will try to make one soon! My own code is too big for this issue.

Comment: while making a reprodible example as a side effect I figured out what caused the problem I was dealing with: when R executes the nested scriptscript_that_builds_the_grid.R, it doesn't recognice the new paramaters. A solution is to load the new parameters within that script. Now my shiny app does its job properly.